# the $C^*$ algebra generated by $P_nAP_n$ is isomorphic to $c_0$ direct sum of the algebras $P_nAP_n$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra,if $P_n$ are pairwise orthogonal central projections in $A$. Then the $C^*$ algebra generated by $P_nAP_n$ is isomorphic to $c_0$ direct sum of the algebras $P_nAP_n$.

My question is: how to show the $C^*$ algebra generated by $P_nAP_n$ is  isomorphic to $c_0$ direct sum of the algebras $P_nAP_n$? why the generated algebra cannot be isomorphic to $l^\infty$ direct sum of the algebras $P_nAP_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an obvious reason why the $\ell^\infty$ sum does not work, start with $A=c_0$, and take $P_n=e_n$. The $\ell^\infty$ sum is $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, which is not separable while $A$ is.

Let us call $B$ your subalgebra. Since the projections $\{P_n\}$ are pairwise orthogonal, any product of the form $(P_nTP_n)(P_mSP_m)$ is zero.

The C$^*$-algebra generated by a set consists of all the closure of all the noncommutative polynomials on the generators and their adjoints. The aforementioned behaviour of the products guarantees that $B$ is the closure of the elements of the form 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m P_{n_j}T_jP_{n_j},
$$
for all different choices $n_1,\ldots,n_m$. Again the orthogonality implies that 
$$
\left\|\sum_{j=1}^m P_{n_j}T_jP_{n_j}\right\|=\max\left\{\|P_{n_j}T_jP_{n_j}\|:\ j\right\}.
$$
It follows that the map 
$$
\Phi:\sum_{j=1}^m P_{n_j}T_jP_{n_j}\longmapsto \bigoplus_{j=1}^m P_{n_j}T_jP_{n_j}
$$
is well-defined, isometric, $*$-homomorphism. As such it extends uniquely to the closure, giving us a $*$-isomorphism $\phi:B\to \bigoplus_{c_0}P_nAP_n.$.

Comment: Very helpful!Thank u so much.

Comment: I am still a little puzzled about the last sentence.why is the closure of $\bigoplus_{j=1}^m P_{n_j}T_jP_{n_j}$ is $\bigoplus_{c_0}P_nAP_n$.Should we check that the sequence is norm convergent to 0?

Comment: Can you prove that the closure of $c_{00}$ (sequences with finitely many nonzero terms) in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is $c_0$?

Comment: oh,I see.Thanks

Comment: Pro Argerami,I reconsider this question,If $P_n$ are finite,then $B$ is $*$ isomorphic to finite direct sum of $P_nA_nP_n$,If $P_n$ are countably infinite,$B$ is $*$ isomorphic to $c_0$ direct sum of $P_nA_nP_n$.When  $P_n$ are uncountably infinite,is $B$ also $*$ isomorphic to $c_0$ direct sum of $P_nA_nP_n$?Please forgive my foolishness!

Comment: The answer still applies verbatim; the only change would be to consider the sums over arbitrary finite sets (instead of "$j=1,\ldots,m $").

Comment: Pro Aregerami,I was obsessed by the definition of $c_0$ direct sum".Is it a set of functions?In above example,  Is $\bigoplus_{c_0}P_nAP_n$  the set of functions whose domain is nature number $\mathbb{N}$?So there are uncountably many elements in $\bigoplus_{c_0}P_nAP_n$?

Comment: Assuming you mean "components" and not "elements", it depends on what the index set is.

Comment: In the above,the index set of $\bigoplus_{c_0}P_nAP_n$ is $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I was always assuming that using $n$ for your indices meant you were indexing over the naturals.